# Create/Enable Option For Different Store View

Tags: magento2

I have an extension that practically when I change store view I no longer have the possibility to change the text or options.

Look at the photo.

in the main website there are all the options, but when I move to a different store view, in the case of the "English" photo the options are no longer available, is there a way to enable them in all the store views? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the system.xml from the extension in a custom module to add `showInStore="1"`.

*Vendor/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/system.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="SECTION_ID_TO_MODIFY">
            <group id="GROUP_ID_TO_MODIFY">
                <field id="FIELD_ID_TO_MODIFY" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1"">
                </field>  
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

Don't forget to override the extension module

*Vendor/ModuleName/etc/module.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_YourModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="EXTENSION_MODULE_TO_MODIFY"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Then, maybe you will have to modify the getConfig function to get the value by store.